# Empty List Android Studio

Tags: php, android, json, listview, empty-list

Why do i get empty list on my phone. Can some 1 help ? It shows correct 7 positions but they are empty.
There is my php file its probbably ok. I use json encode.

```
public class ClientActivity extends UserAreaActivity {

private String jsonResult;
private String url = "http://vinusek.000webhostapp.com/Client2.php";
private ListView listView;
private TextView nazwa;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_client);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    nazwa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2) ;
    accessWebService();
}

// Async Task to access the web
private class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
        }

        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        String rLine = "";
        StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        try {
            while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                answer.append(rLine);
            }
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Error..." + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return answer;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        ListDrwaer();
    }
}// end async task

public void accessWebService() {
    JsonReadTask task = new JsonReadTask();
    // passes values for the urls string array
    task.execute(new String[] { url });
}

// build hash set for list view
public void ListDrwaer() {
    List<Map<String, String>> employeeList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    try {

        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
        JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("result");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
            String number = jsonChildNode.getString("id");
            String name = jsonChildNode.getString("login");
            String pass = jsonChildNode.getString("haslo");
            String outPut = number + "-" +  name + "-" + pass;
            employeeList.add(createEmployee("list", outPut));
            nazwa.setText(outPut);
        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(ClientActivity.this, employeeList,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            new String[] {"list"}, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
    listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
}

private HashMap<String, String> createEmployee(String name, String number) {
    HashMap<String, String> employeeNameNo = new HashMap<String, String>();
    employeeNameNo.put(number, name);
    return employeeNameNo;
}}
```

What is wrong here, i got the code from here http://codeoncloud.blogspot.in/2013/07/android-mysql-php-json-tutorial.html
and it works for his php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [`SimpleAdapter` class reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html):

As you can see, the constructor takes the following arguments :

```
SimpleAdapter (Context context, 
               List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, 
               int resource, 
               String[] from, 
               int[] to)
```

> 1. context     Context: The context where the View associated with this SimpleAdapter is running
> 2. **data  List: A List of Maps. Each entry in the List corresponds to one row in the list**. **The Maps contain the data for each row, and should include all the entries specified in "from"**
> 3. resource    int: Resource identifier of a view layout that defines the views for this list item. The layout file should include at least those named views defined in "to"
> 4. **from  String: A list of column names that will be added to the Map associated with each item**.
> 5. to  int: The views that should display column in the "from" parameter. These should all be TextViews. The first N views in this list are given the values of the first N columns in the from parameter.

You instantiate the `SimpleAdapter` with :

```
SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(ClientActivity.this, employeeList,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            new String[] {"list"}, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
```

This means that each element of your `employeeList` `List` should be a `Map` that contains the key "list".

Therefore

```
employeeList.add(createEmployee("list", outPut));
```

should add to the `List` a `Map` having an entry with the key "list" and the value `outPut`.

However, your `createEmployee()` method creates a `HashMap` with a single entry where the key and the value are swapped.

You should change

```
private HashMap<String, String> createEmployee(String name, String number) {
    HashMap<String, String> employeeNameNo = new HashMap<String, String>();
    employeeNameNo.put(number, name);
    return employeeNameNo;
}
```

to

```
private HashMap<String, String> createEmployee(String name, String number) {
    HashMap<String, String> employeeNameNo = new HashMap<String, String>();
    employeeNameNo.put(name, number);
    return employeeNameNo;
}
```